# Post to Facebook via Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, facebook, actionscript

Is there a way to post to a users Facebook wall via fbConnect? (php/as3)

I can authenticate and pull info but not post anything. I have searched extensively and not found a working example or docs on how to post directly via AS3. My current work around is to external link to an Ajax page. blah.

J~

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked here? I thought you could do pretty much everything with this API

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/

Comment: Yeah, I've gone through all the devnet stuff. All I can find is how to 'GET' info... nothing on posting to the wall other than via JS.